# Plotting a graph but having range issues

Tags: python

Here is my code to draw a graph, but i am not understanding the error please help

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

l=np.linspace(0,2001,100)
c=3*(10**8)
h=6.626*(10**-34)
K=1.38*(10**-23)
E=[]
for i in range(100,2001):
    y=2*(math.pi)*h*(c**2)/((l[i]**5)*math.exp((h*c/l[i]*K*T)-1))
    E.append(y)

plt.plot(l,E)
plt.show
```

Here is the error:

```
y=2*(math.pi)*h*(c**2)/((l[i]**5)*math.exp((h*c/l[i]*K*T)-1))
IndexError: index 100 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 100
```

Please help me understand

Answer (score 4):

That's because `np.linspace(0,2001,100)` produces an array ranging from 0 to 2001 but with only 100 points, thus `l[100]` is out of bounds.

On a completely different tone : you should definitely try vectorization, a powerful tool supported by numpy arrays that makes code easier to implement :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l = np.linspace(0,2001,100)
c = 3*(10**8)
h = 6.626*(10**-34)
K = 1.38*(10**-23)
y = 2*np.pi*h*(c**2) / ( (l**5)*np.exp((h*c/l*K*T)-1) )

plt.plot(l,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: But the problem is that using your code, i am getting maximum at 2, but mine gives maximum at 1 after fixing the error. why is that?

Comment: what is the code you are using? How did you fixed the error?

Comment: I have resubmitted the question in this thread with the graphs included. Can you please help me out?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63302533/plotting-graphs-with-similar-codes

Comment: got it solved. it was an error in the expression from my side. sorry. thank you bro