# Plotting graphs with similar codes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I plotted my graph with this code:

```
from numpy import*
from matplotlib.pyplot import*
h=6.626*10**(-34)
c=3*10**8
k=1.38*10**(-23)
t=6000
l=[]
s=arange(100,2000,1)
def fun(x,t):
    e=(2*pi*h*c**2)/(x**5*(exp((h*c)/(x*k*t))-1))
    return e
for x in arange(100*10**(-9),2000*10**(-9),1*10**(-9)):
    r=fun(x,t)
    l.append(r)
plot(s,l)
show()
```

And courtesy to RandomGuy, he gave a much compact code:

```
from numpy import*
from matplotlib.pyplot import*
h=6.626*10**(-34)
c=3*10**8
T=6000
k=1.38*10**(-23)
l=linspace(100*10**(-9),2001*10**(-9),100)
E=(2*pi*h*c**2)/((l**5)*exp(h*c/(l*k*T)-1))
plot(l,E)
show
```

But the problem is, I am getting different maximas for the peaks. In the first one, it is near 1, but for the second, it is more than 2.5. What makes these codes different?

[image: graph of first code]

[image: graph of second code]

Comment: What is the value of `k` in the first example?

Comment: i have edited it. its the same as in code 2

Comment: The customary way to write `100*10**(-9)` is to use scientific notation and have it as `100E-9` (etc).

Answer (score 3):

The difference comes from the argument of the exponential.

In the second function, `-1` is in the argument of `exp` which is not the case for the first one.

Comment: Actually, they are not. Look carefully at the expression you have for `E` in the second example vs. the expression for `e` in the first example. They are indeed different functions.

Comment: oh you are right. sorry my bad. i am stupid. thank you Pi-R and Basil. Love you.

Comment: Also, why do you plot on different intervals between the two examples? In the first, it's on `[100..2000]` but in the second it's on `[100*10^-9..2000*10-9]`.

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit:  `np.exp(h*c/(x*k*t))-1` vs `np.exp(h*c/(x*k*t)-1)`

Comment: @basil In the 1st graph they do not `plot(x, l)` but `plot(s, l)` where `s` goes from 100 to 2000, probably the (laudable) intent is to label the _x_-axis with nano-somethin'